# RSS pagination - how feedly can paginates an url

Tags: xml, pagination, rss

I've this RSS link that I want to paginate :
http://feeds.folha.uol.com.br/ambiente/rss091.xml

I can see that feedly can easily paginate this url:
http://feedly.com/i/subscription/feed/http://feeds.folha.uol.com.br/ambiente/rss091.xml%0A%09%09%09%09

However, I've been trying many ways to paginate this without success (?page=2 or ?paged=2, looking into source code etc...). There is any protocol that this RSS must follow to be paginated? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feedly is able to paginate because they have been *saving* this feed's content for a long time. In the vast majority of cases, an RSS feed is a window of content. It includes only the last X entries of any news source (blog, news site... etc) and should mostly be looked at as a "forward" subscription mechanism. Once you've subscribed to the feed you will get its upcoming content, not its past.

APIs like [Superfeedr](https://superfeedr.com) let you also retrieve past content from feeds.